Python Colab Turtle Tic Tac Toe drawing circles off centre for no reason
def square(x):
  for i in range(4):
    allmight.pendown()
    allmight.forward(x)
    allmight.right(90)
def nextshape(jump):
  allmight.penup()
  allmight.forward(jump)
  allmight.pendown()
def nextrow():
  allmight.penup()
  allmight.setheading(180)
  allmight.forward(300)
  allmight.setheading(270)
  allmight.forward(100)
def printboard():
  print(board[0])
  print(board[1])
  print(board[2])
def go():
  row = int(input("which row do you want to place in? (1 is top, 2 is middle, 3 is bottom)"))
  column = int(input("which column do you want to place in? (1 is left, 2 is middle, 3 is right)"))
  while board[row-1][column-1] != " ":
    row = int(input("which row do you want to place in? (1 is top, 2 is middle, 3 is bottom)"))
    column = int(input("which column do you want to place in? (1 is left, 2 is middle, 3 is right)"))
  xvalue = boardx[row-1][column-1]
  yvalue = boardy[row-1][column-1]
  if piece == "o":
    board[row-1][column-1] = "o"
    circle(xvalue,yvalue)
  if piece == "x":
    board[row-1][column-1] = "x"
    cross(xvalue,yvalue)
def check_won():
  won = False
  if board[0][0] == board[0][1] and board[0][1] == board[0][2]:
    if board[0][0] != " ":
      won = True
  elif board[1][0] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[1][2]:
    if board[1][0] != " ":
      won = True
  elif board[2][0] == board[2][1] and board[2][1] == board[2][2]:
    if board[2][0] != " ":
      won = True
  elif board[0][0] == board[1][0] and board[1][0] == board[2][0]:
    if board[0][0] != " ":
      won = True
  elif board[0][1] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[2][1]:
    if board[0][1] != " ":
      won = True
  elif board[0][2] == board[1][2] and board[1][2] == board[2][2]:
    if board[0][2] != " ":
      won = True
  elif board[0][0] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
    if board[0][0] != " ":
      won = True
  elif board[0][2] == board[1][1] and board[1][1] == board[2][0]:
    if board[0][2] != " ":
      won = True
  return won
def opponentgo():
  print('not yet')
def opponentgorandom():
  opponentx = random.randint(0,2)
  opponenty = random.randint(0,2)
  opponentgo = board[opponentx][opponenty]
  while opponentgo != " ":
    opponentx = random.randint(0,2)
    opponenty = random.randint(0,2)
    opponentgo = board[opponentx][opponenty]
  xvalue = boardx[opponentx][opponenty]
  yvalue = boardy[opponentx][opponenty]
  board[opponentx][opponenty] = opponentpiece
  if opponentpiece == "o":
    circle(xvalue,yvalue)
    print(xvalue)
    print(yvalue)
  if opponentpiece == "x":
    cross(xvalue,yvalue)
    print(xvalue)
    print(yvalue)
def circle(x,y):
  allmight.goto(x-35,y)
  print(allmight.pos())
  allmight.pendown()
  allmight.circle(35)
  allmight.penup()
  allmight.goto(x,y)
def cross(x,y):
  for count in range(0,4):
    allmight.goto(x,y)
    allmight.down()
    allmight.setheading(45+(90*count))
    allmight.forward(55)
  allmight.penup()
import ColabTurtlePlus.Turtle as allmight
import random
allmight.initializeTurtle((300,300), 'standard', 10)
allmight.clear()
allmight.speed(13)
allmight.bgcolor("rgb(240 248 255)")
allmight.pencolor("rgb(0 0 0)")
allmight.fillcolor("rgb(255 127 80)")
allmight.penup()
allmight.goto(-150,150)
allmight.pendown()
board = [[" ", " ", " "],
         [" ", " ", " "],
         [" ", " ", " "]]
boardx = [[-100,0,100],
          [-100,0,100],
          [-100,0,100]]
boardy = [[100,100,100],
          [0,  0,  0],
          [-100,-100,-100]]
for item in range(0,3):
  for count in range(0,3):
    allmight.setheading(0)
    square(100)
    nextshape(100)
  nextrow()
piece = str(input("Do you want to be noughts(enter o) or crosses(enter x)"))
while piece != "o" and piece != "x":
  piece = str(input("Do you want to be noughts(enter o) or crosses(enter x)"))
if piece == "o":
  opponentpiece = "x"
if piece == "x":
  opponentpiece = "o"
if opponentpiece == "o":
  board[0][0] = "o"
  circle(-100,100)
if opponentpiece == "x":
  board[0][0] = "x"
  cross(-100,100)
printboard()
go()
haswon = check_won()
printboard()
while haswon == False:
  opponentgorandom()
  printboard()
  go()
  haswon = check_won()
  print("")
  printboard()
print("somebody won")

print(board[0])
print(board[1])
print(board[2])


if the code starts the first circle wont be off centre but the rest will be
I tried changing some of the values, but that just made the first circle which was on centre offcentre, so I am pretty sure the problem lies within the later parts of the code somewhere. The code creates a 2d array version which works fine, the only problem is the drawing of the circle. The crosses are always on centre even though they use very similar code. I can't really see any obvious solution so if someone could spot one that would be great.

The turtle .circle() method produces a circle that extends to the left of the turtle - so not only the position of the turtle matters, but also the direction it is facing.  One fix would be to use .setheading() to face a fixed direction, before trying to draw the circle.

There have been a number of similar tic tac toe turtle questions the past couple days on different accounts. Consider making one account and trying to write higher-quality questions. Thanks.

Plopping your code into https://black.vercel.app/ and pasting the result back into the question would be a good thing.
